# Change Prototype to jQuery Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, toggle, prototype

I'd like to change my Ajax call from Prototype to jQuery. But somehow, things are not yet working. ..... A few hours later, getting a clearer picture, things are working.

In order to give others the possibility to see how the "migration" can be done, I post this nevertheless...

My orginial Prototype is this:

```
<li>
    <a href='#' onclick="variables(); Effect.toggle('datasets','BLIND'); return false;">
        <div class='additionalLinksMenuBar'>&nbsp;</div>
        <div class='tableName additionalLinksMenuLink'>define dataset</div>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <div id='datasets' style='display:none; border: 1px solid #00115a; background-color: #FFF6D1; text-align: left; margin-left: 8px; padding: 12px 10px;'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function variables()
            {
                var url = 'http://my_url/etc/php/fill_variable_list.php'; 
                var target = 'output-div'; 
                var pars = 'selectedKeyword=cereals&selected_ids=&selectedDatasettype=1&p=';
                var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater(target, url, {method: 'get', parameters: pars});
            }
        </script>

        <br />

        <div id='output-div'></div>

        <script> 
            $('output-div').insert(new Element('form', { id:'form_define_dataset' })) 
        </script> 

    </div>
</li>
```

And my new jQuery is this:

```
<li>
    <a href='#' onclick="variables(); $('#datasets').slideToggle('slow'); return false;">
        <div class='additionalLinksMenuBar'>&nbsp;</div>
        <div class='tableName additionalLinksMenuLink'>define dataset</div>
    </a>
</li>   
<li>
    <div id='datasets' style='display:none; border: 1px solid #00115a; background-color: #FFF6D1; text-align: left; margin-left: 8px; padding: 12px 10px;'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function variables()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://my_url/etc/php/fill_variable_list.php',
                    data: 'selectedKeyword=cereals&selected_ids=&selectedDatasettype=1&p=',
                    dataType: 'html'
                })

                .done(function( html ) {
                    $( '#output-div' ).append( html );
                });

            }
        </script>

        <br />

        <div id='output-div'></div>

    </div>
</li>
```

#

Answer (score 0):

The conversion of code seems to be totally correct.

Try the following code to see the exception you are getting

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://my_url/etc/php/fill_variable_list.php',
                    data: 'selectedKeyword=cereals&selected_ids=&selectedDatasettype=1&p=',
                    dataType: 'html'
                })

                .done(function( html ) {
                    $( '#output-div' ).append( html );
                })

                .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                });
```